# How to do introduce data of calendar type ahead for two months without hard coding?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am creating a database at moment and I am stuck a bit at the logical part of it. 
The project what I do is a system that would allow users to check the train and bus schedule by selecting hour and date. And here I am a bit confused and do not know how to make it right.

It is a web app using php and for db we use mysql.

**So the problem is:** There is a route, ex: City1 - City2. On this route operates more operators, let's say Op1 and Op2. Each operator has multiple time departures per day from the City1 to City2. Until this moment for me everything is clear but now comes the part to introduce Date for each time.

*How to do that? Because I need to introduce date(s) ahead for two months for example. What are the best practices to do that? Do I really need to do all the hard way data entry stuff?*

*Are any ways, for example, to create the schedule for the first week(Monday to Sunday) and then programmatically to copy all that week for the next ones?*

Thank you,

Comment: No details about the system that's going to use the database. No specification about which DBMS is going to be used. Hard to answer such a broad question.

Comment: The database can generate the data for you with Joins. You can enter base times in one table, the calendar in another table, cross join them and viola, you have all combinations of dates and times, which you can then insert into another table.

Comment: @Alfabravo Sorry, new here, and what I am trying to do is also new for me. Hope you understand. We want to create a web application that will display the bus schedule. For db we use Mysql.

Comment: @RBarryYoung make sense that, but the I was wondering if do I need to insert all the combination for one month ahead manually or is it a easier way to do it?

Comment: Yes better title. Unfortunately: (a) this is a rather broad question for a Stack Exchange, (b) more appropriate for the [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) than here, and (c) has been asked many times already such as [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/63106/19079). Search for "recurring event" here and on the DBA site.

Comment: MariaDB has a "sequence" set of tables that let you generate arbitrary integers (hence, dates).

Answer (score 0):

The result data for making report is DateTime of departures in requested interval. It's don't matter for end result how you will get this data by request from database or by request and algorithm processing . But you can consider other factors like performance, time of processing, memory consumption or admin UI of system for making decision about design.